# Making velocity of an SKSprite node relative to parent (not view/scene)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm using SpriteKit in Swift (3.0).

I store all the SKSprites nodes in my game as children of a "world" node

However when I apply a velocity to one of those nodes, they move relative to the screen, and not "world" (world is rotating, moving, etc.)

Heres how I implement it:

```
    let movingObject = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    movingObject.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: movingObject.size)
    movingObject.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 200)
    world.addChild(movingObject)
```

I need my node's velocity to move in respect to its parent, not the scene/view it is in. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This might not be much help, but you could keep your world still, and all objects relative to that world, and use a camera to create the impression of rotation and movement to the player.

Comment: @Confused thanks but as far as I'm aware there is not an implementation of a "camera" node in Swift. On the apple documentation they suggest you create a "world" node and move/rotate that around to create the illusion of a camera.

Comment: There is a camera node in swift - it's called SKCameraNode. There are other tutorials online on how to use it and it's a useful thing to have.

Comment: @claassenApps How did I not know about this! When you look it up on apple documentation, it suggests you make a world node. Thankyou

Comment: @claassenApps after reading implimentation of a CameraNode https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skcameranode it looks like my gameworld is going to be moved anyway? Does the velocity stay relative to the camera?

Comment: The beauty of the SKCameraNode is that it's kind of a separate thing - since it's a child of SKNode, you use any SKAction on the camera that you could on any other node. This gives you total control over where the camera is moved and how it's rotated.